# Qt4 or Qt5 (mingw) and openCV 2.4.6

Tags: qt, opencv, mingw

I have problems with setting up Qt with opencv:

With Qt5 cMake unable to finish the configuration. Luckily with Qt4 it works fine. (default only Qt)

mingw32-make 
mingw32-make install

(this runs without error)

But when I use InputVideo which is in highgui, it stops runtime. 
Checking with dependecy walker, the LIBOPENCV_HIGHGUI246.DLL has dependecies like:

API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL 
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL 
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL 
...

these are in theory part of windows8. How can i fix this problem?

(besides moving all dll-s near my executable)

Comment: Many of those dependencies are actually filled-in by Windows somehow. Can you describe better your error? For example, do you get an Access Violation while the program is running, or the program never runs and Windows just says that a dll is missing?

Comment: The program cant start, because these dll-s are missing. If i start from QtCreator gives the following error: exited with code -1073741502

Answer (score 0):

I managed to configure a Qt Creator project with OpenCV to run a simple OpenCV application I wrote recently, named [cvDisplacementMapFilter](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvDisplacementMapFilter).

I tested it with **OpenCV 2.4.7** on Mac OS X 10.7.5 and OpenCV 2.4.2 on Windows 7. I believe the following **.pro** file can help you:

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

# On my system I have to specify g++ as compiler else it will use clang++ by default
QMAKE_CXX=g++
QMAKE_CC=gcc

## OpenCV settings for Unix/Linux
unix:!mac {
    message("* Using settings for Unix/Linux.")
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv

    LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ \
        -lopencv_core \
        -lopencv_highgui \
        -lopencv_imgproc
}

## OpenCV settings for Mac OS X
macx {
    message("* Using settings for Mac OS X.")
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv

    LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ \
        -lopencv_core \
        -lopencv_highgui \
        -lopencv_imgproc
}

## OpenCV settings for Windows and OpenCV 2.4.2
win32 {
    message("* Using settings for Windows.")
    INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\opencv\\build\\include" \
                   "C:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv" \
                   "C:\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv2"

    LIBS += -L"C:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib" \
        -lopencv_core242 \
        -lopencv_highgui242 \
        -lopencv_imgproc242
}
```

Don't forget to change the paths and version of OpenCV at `win32`.